# Not receiving push notifications on LTE networ, iOS swift

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications, lte

I have the problem with apple push notification I have **iPhone 7, iOS 11.2.1** when my mobile data on I couldn't receive a push notification on LTE network some time I get notification sometime not.

when I switch to my wifi network or other networks I received all notification on time.

I have updated my device token. and **valid provisioning profile**.

notification permission all the is ok.

Comment: maybe your LTE connection is weak. Did you try with other apps?

Comment: I am facing the same issue on my all the apps. Did you find any solution?

Comment: sorry for late reply @Honey I change the network but the same issue I was facing. and also try with other apps.